# how to plot a function that depends on integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have a problem with plotting the following function:

```
Clear[f]
f[t_,s_] :=   2/Pi Integrate[ (Sin[w] Cos[wt])/w, {w, 0, s}]
Plot[[f[t,4]], {t, -4 , 4 }]
Plot[[f[t,8]], {t, -4 , 4 }]
```

Comment: You are lucky here that there's a closed form you can use: `f[t_, s_] := (SinIntegral[s (t + 1)] - SinIntegral[s (t - 1)])/2`.

Comment: @J.M.: +1! This I've overseen ;-)

Comment: @mgamer, not too late to edit your answer to include it... ;P

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code: 
First a syntax problem, you should write `Cos[w*t]` in the integration, second do not use `Integrate`this tries to solve the integral symbolically. So do :

```
f[t_, s_] := 2/Pi NIntegrate[(Sin[w] Cos[w*t])/w, {w, 0, s}]
```

and (only one pair of [] in the plot command!)

```
Plot[f[t, 4], {t, -4, 4}]
```

and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is almost four times faster:

```
Clear[f];
f[t_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 2./Pi NIntegrate[(Sin[w] Cos[w t])/w, {w, 0, s}, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}]
Plot[{f[t, 4.], f[t, 8.]}, {t, -4, 4}]
```

[image]